# syncfusion uwp diagram mvvm command

Tags: xaml, uwp, syncfusion

I'm trying to add an gesture-command (del-key pressed) to the commandmanager of syncfusion's diagram.
I've tried something like:

```
<diagram:SfDiagram Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Nodes="{Binding Nodes}" 
                   Connectors="{Binding Connectors}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource Diagram}"
                   >
    <diagram:SfDiagram.Info>
        <diagram:CommandManager>
            <diagram:CommandManager.Commands>
                <diagram:GestureCommand>
                </diagram:GestureCommand>
            </diagram:CommandManager.Commands>
        </diagram:CommandManager>
    </diagram:SfDiagram.Info>

</diagram:SfDiagram>
```

but i think I'm missing something here.

my question: how can I add an Event to the diagram-commandmanager using XAML and MVVM.

Comment: have you tried key up and key down events if the "Del" key is what you're referring to?

Comment: yes I've tried that but couldn't get it to work. I would like to react on the build-in-Events of the diagram-control

Comment: Try contacting SF support, they'll be able to better address your question. Also personally I would have used telerik as it's open sourced now and they have much better support

Comment: telerik is not open source http://www.telerik.com/devcraft . It's expansive. Syncfusion is free for single developer like me.

Comment: It is. https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP and https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk these are the two places. You will not need to add the entire referance and hence your size would not be affected much. you can simply pull out the control and put it in your app

Comment: thanks. I will have a look at this